# Release new Alpha to Playstore while production waits for scheduled release

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, release-management

I have a scheduled release waiting for me to push „Go Live“ in production track on Playstore. It seems like this also affects other tracks now, however I‘d like in the meantime to test another version already on alpha track. Can I release Alpha separately from Production? I am afraid releasing Alpha would now at the same time prematurely unleash Production.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so answering my own question now after the time for release came anyway: the schedule is a global switch, stopping all playstore release activities on all tracks. They are collected in an activity queue and once you decide to go live, all queued activities are released at once (you can review that activity list first). So you actually can't continue working on other tracks while a scheduled release is in place.